# SWIG: "out" typemap for structure field needs to access another field of the same structure

Tags: c, swig

I am attempting to wrap a C library (which I did not write, and whose interfaces cannot be changed) using SWIG.  It's mostly straightforward, but there's one field of one `struct` that's giving me trouble.  The relevant `struct` definition looks like this:

```
struct Token {
    const char *buffer;
    const char *word;
    unsigned short wordlen;
    // ... other fields ...
};
```

`buffer` is a normal C string and should be exposed normally (but immutably).  `word` is the problem field.  It is a pointer to somewhere *within* the `buffer` string, and is meant to be understood as a string of length `wordlen`.  I want to expose this to high-level languages as a normal read-only string, so they don't always have to be taking a slice.

I *think* the way to handle this is with an "out" typemap specifically for `Token::word`, something like this:

```
struct Token {
    %typemap (out) const char *word {
        $result = SWIG_FromCharPtrAndSize($1, ?wordlen?);
    }
}
```

and this is where I got stuck: *How do I access the `wordlen` field of the parent structure from this typemap?*

Or if there's a better way to handle this entire issue, please tell me about that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like SWIG has no support for mapping multiple structure members at the same time. Inspecting the generated output we learn that `(arg1)` points to the input structure. Thus, we have to:

1. Make the `word` immutable, so that the `set` wrapper is not generated.
2. Import the `SWIG_FromCharPtrAndSize` fragment - it's not available by default.
3. Map `word` using `SWIG_FromCharPtrAndSize` as you wished, referring to `(arg1)->wordlen`.
4. Skip `wordlen`, so that it's not mapped (either by `%ignore`-ing it, or not providing it in the `struct` visible to SWIG).

The following is a complete example. First, the header:

```
// main.h
#pragma once

struct Token {
  const char *word;
  unsigned short wordlen;
};

struct Token *make_token(void);
extern char *word_check;
```

And the SWIG module - note that we use the header verbatim, only overriding the definition of `struct Token`:

```
// token_mod.i
%module token_mod
%{#include "main.h"%}
%ignore Token;
%include "main.h"
%rename("%s") Token;

struct Token {
  %immutable word;
  %typemap (out, fragment="SWIG_FromCharPtrAndSize") const char *word {
    $result = SWIG_FromCharPtrAndSize($1, (arg1)->wordlen);
  }
  const char *word;
  %typemap (out) const char *word;
};
```

The demo code that uses Python to check that things work:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/swig-pair-53915787
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include "main.h"

struct Token *make_token(void) {
  struct Token *r = malloc(sizeof(struct Token));
  r->word = "1234";
  r->wordlen = 2;
  return r;
}

char *word_check;

#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000
#  define SWIG_init    PyInit__token_mod
PyObject*
#else
#  define SWIG_init    init_token_mod
void
#endif
SWIG_init(void);

int main()
{
   PyImport_AppendInittab("_token_mod", SWIG_init);
   Py_Initialize();
   PyRun_SimpleString(
            "import sys\n"
            "sys.path.append('.')\n"
            "import token_mod\n"
            "from token_mod import *\n"
            "token = make_token()\n"
            "cvar.word_check = token.word\n");
   assert(word_check && strcmp(word_check, "12") == 0);
   Py_Finalize();
   return 0;
}
```

Finally, the `CMakeLists.txt` that makes the demo - it can be used with Python 2.7 or 3.x. Note: To switch Python versions, the build directory must be wiped (or at least the cmake caches in it have to be wiped).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

set(Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 3.6)
project(swig-pair)
find_package(SWIG 3.0 REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs 3.6 REQUIRED)
include(UseSwig)

SWIG_MODULE_INITIALIZE(${PROJECT_NAME} python)
SWIG_ADD_SOURCE_TO_MODULE(${PROJECT_NAME} swig_generated_sources "token_mod.i")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.c" ${swig_generated_sources})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} ".")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score -2):

The higher level languages don't care that wordlen is the size of word. Only the C does. If you cant change the C that you are swiging then you have to leave it as is and remember as you write in the higher languages that the char has a size. Also Swig and const don't like each other. [Here](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn12)is there documentation on consts